How to Address a PhD Student in an Email: Mr. or Dr.?
I am preparing to send an email to a PhD student and am unsure of the appropriate title to use in my greeting. Is it more appropriate to address them as Mr./Ms. or as Dr., considering they are still in the process of completing their doctoral studies? I want to ensure that my communication is both respectful and correctly formatted according to academic norms.

Please avoid posting answers in the comments. Instead, please vote on the existing answers or add another answer if you have something to add. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question, or asking for clarification.

In what country do they reside?

He is from the USA. @AzorAhai-him-

Someone in a doctoral program is a student, not a doctor. Unless they have completed a doctoral program (technically graduated from one) it isn't appropriate to call them "doctor" or use Dr. in a title.
Some people compromise a bit between having the dissertation accepted and the official graduation by calling the person Doctor, as graduation and the conferring of the degree and title is usually just a formality then.
Even having graduated from a medical program it probably requires that they be called Mr. or Ms. or similar until they are licensed (most places). Licensing of medical practitioners is separate from graduation.
I'll note that some people here write "I'm a PhD" meaning not that they have completed a degree, for which this would be appropriate, but actually meaning "I'm a PhD student or candidate". But it isn't a PhD until you complete it.

I think it would be taken oddly if you insisted on referring to an MD who hasn't been licensed yet as "M[rs].," but you may be technically right.

"I'll note that some people here write "I'm a PhD" meaning not that they have completed a degree …" This may be a language thing. Around here (German university) you are either a "doctoral/PhD student" or a "doctor" once you are done. As a result, "I'm a PhD" is meaningless aside from being a lazy short form for the former. And people love being lazy.

In an effort to communicate as inclusively as possible and to not assume anyones gender or prefered way of being addressed, I would suggest to neither use Ms./Mr. (which also avoids the sexist can of worms hidden behing Ms. and Mrs.) nor Dr. (as a PhD student will in the majority of cases will not have obtained their doctorate yet, as others have quite correctly pointed out), but rather address them as

Dear Firstname Lastname, ...

This gender neutral address should be perfectly fine in any occasion (that is not only for students) where a more formal address like professor or Dr. is not applicable.

I'm inclined to point out that, while this works in English, it tends not to work in languages which require gender specific flexion of adjectives (such as, for instance, French or German).

@JochenGlueck, of course that is true, English does make it comparably easier than the more gender-heavy languages, yet even in German or French a "Salut/Bonjour Firstname Lastname" or "Guten Tag/Hallo Firstname Lastname" still works, although probably slightly less formal than the gender specific "Liebe/ Lieber Firstname Lastname"

@Sursual: Yes, in German I also sometimes go with "Guten Tag xyz", though it feels slightly off in some contexts.

Many Unis nowadays (including mine) actually ask PhD students/staff to declare their preferred pronouns; and the OP sounded pretty confident that they are getting in touch with him as opposed to her. Regardless tho, I do think your suggestion would work quite well

If anyone emailed me calling me Mr/Mrs when I was a graduate student, I would feel that they were after something, so I'd get suspicious of them and probably wouldn't respond. If they called me Doctor, I'd think they were clueless, so I wouldn't bother responding either. Just go with "Dear John," "Dear Mary," "Dear whatever." It's more personable and effective, I'd say.

It is worth to mention that this is culture-dependent. But I'd agree in the context of the US. I personally prefer even more if I receive "Hi First_Name".
